# Skip parametrized tests generated by pytest_generate_tests at module level

Tags: python, pytest

I would like to be able to parametrize a couple of tests from a config file, but at the same time being able to skip those tests unless a specific command option is issued.

I can skip tests by adding the following code at the top of the test module:

```
from json import loads
import pytest
@pytest.mark.skipif(pytest.config.getvalue("-k") != "smoke",
                    reason="Smoke tests must be explicitly launched through -k smoke option")
```

The tests are not executed when issuing `py.test` or `python -m pytest` unless the option `-k smoke` is added.

I also can create parametrized tests from config files by:

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    with open('tests/test_smoke.json','r') as fp:
        confs = loads(fp.read().decode("utf-8-sig"))

        for arg in metafunc.funcargnames:
            if arg == "conf":
                metafunc.parametrize("conf",confs)
```

And example of test that is parametrized would be:

```
def test_that_require_conf(conf):
    assert not conf
```

The problem is that both things do not work nicely together. The test is not skipped when `pytest_generate_tests` is used.
If I add an option in `pytest_generate_tests` in order to avoid the parametrization, then the call yo `pytest` fails because
`conf` fixture required by `test_that_require_conf` can not be found.

Any idea about how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options:
 (I supposed that your option is stored as `smoke`)

1) in the first option you need to change your `pytest_generate_tests`. The tests will be skipped as one

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    for arg in metafunc.funcargnames:
         if arg == "conf":
            if metafunc.config.option.keyword != 'smoke':
                confs = pytest.skip("Smoke tests must....")
            else:
                with open('tests/test_smoke.json', 'r') as fp:
                    confs = loads(fp.read().decode("utf-8-sig"))

            metafunc.parametrize("conf", confs)
```

the output will be:

```
collected 0 items / 1 skipped

==================== 1 skipped in 0.01 seconds ========================
```

2) The second options will skip any test individually

```
def test_that_require_conf(request, conf):
    if request.config.option.smoke != 'smoke':
        pytest.skip('Smoke tests must....")
    assert conf
```

the output will

```
collected 3 items

tests/test_2.py::test_that_require_conf[1] SKIPPED
tests/test_2.py::test_that_require_conf[2] SKIPPED
tests/test_2.py::test_that_require_conf[3] SKIPPED

====================== 3 skipped in 0.02 seconds ======================
```